# Refreshing the choices in a QComboBox used as an editor in a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, tableview

I'm using a `QComboxBox` in a `QTableView` in Qt. When I add a new row then `createEditor()` of my delegate is called and I can instantiate the combobox with the correct set of choices available at that time. The problem is, that the user can load different files outside the table, and based on the content of the file the combobox would need to updated their items.
Is there a way that I can get the editor of a cell, so that I can update the choices accordingly? Since other cells of the table should not be destroyed, I can not simply recreate the table with the new data, I need only to update the comboboxes of certain cells.

I've been looking in the sourcecode of `QAbstractItemView` and there is a function `editorForIndex()` which would be exactly what I need, but this is implemented privately inside the view so it is not accessible even in a derived class.
Of course I can keep a record of the boxes that I create, so that I can update them accordingly later on, but I wonder if there is really no other way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the contents of your combobox as a class member of your delegate in a `QStringList`. Your item delegate can be like :

```
#include <QItemDelegate>

#include <QComboBox>

class ComboBoxDelegate: public QItemDelegate
{
 Q_OBJECT
public:
    ComboBoxDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

    QWidget *createEditor( QWidget *parent,
                            const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                            const QModelIndex &index ) const;

    void setEditorData( QWidget *editor,
                            const QModelIndex &index ) const;

    void setModelData( QWidget *editor,
                            QAbstractItemModel *model,
                            const QModelIndex &index ) const;

    void updateEditorGeometry( QWidget *editor,
                            const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                            const QModelIndex &index ) const;

    QStringList comboItems;

    mutable QComboBox *combo;

private slots:

    void setData(int val);

};

ComboBoxDelegate::ComboBoxDelegate(QObject *parent ):QItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget *ComboBoxDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    combo = new QComboBox( parent );
    QObject::connect(combo,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),this,SLOT(setData(int)));
    combo->addItems(comboItems);
    combo->setMaxVisibleItems(comboItems.count());
    return combo;
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QString text = index.model()->data( index, Qt::DisplayRole ).toString();

    int comboIndex = comboItems.indexOf(QRegExp(text));

    if(comboIndex>=0)
        (static_cast<QComboBox*>( editor ))->setCurrentIndex(comboIndex);
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    model->setData( index, static_cast<QComboBox*>( editor )->currentText() );
}


void ComboBoxDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry( option.rect );
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::setData(int val)
{
    emit commitData(combo);
    //emit closeEditor(combo);
}
```

When you want to update the items in combobox somewhere in your code just get a pointer to the item delegate by calling `itemDelegateForColumn` and access the `comboItems` member :

```
ComboBoxDelegate * itemDelegate = (ComboBoxDelegate *)ui->tableView->itemDelegateForColumn(columnIndex);

//Updating combobox items
itemDelegate->comboItems.append("newItem");
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I used an observer pattern now, but it seems the idea is basically the same. I'm not that familiar yet with Qt. :)